# "indef add" as cause of detention?

Tags: united-states, immigration, 1910s, italy

What is the meaning of "indef add" as cause of detention on 1904 ship's record of detained passengers from Italy to US?  Occurred in New York, presumably Ellis Island, though unconfirmed.